# TypeScript difference between any[] and [] when initialize data type

Tags: arrays, typescript, initialization

I used *ngIf to judge the array length in html

```
<div *ngIf="apps.length === 0">
```

and define the apps in .ts file

```
public apps: any[];
```

and apps was retrieved from the rest api data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const refSpinner = this._simsSpinnerService.showSpinner('my-apps-spinner');
    const getMyApps = this._myAppsService.getMyApps().pipe(share(), finalize(() => { this._simsSpinnerService.stopSpinner(refSpinner); }))
    this._subscriptions.push(getMyApps.subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        if (data && data instanceof Array) {
          debugger
          this.apps = data;
        }
      },
      error: (err) => MessageService.addError(err)
    }));
}
```

The console will print error message:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at MyAppsComponent_Template (my-apps.component.html:13:30)
```

I add debugger and found the this.apps is undefined before the data was assigned to it.

Then I changed the way to init data type like:

```
public apps = [];
```

And the error was disappeared, found that this.apps is an array before the data was assigned to it.

I searched and found that

> any[] is an array where the item is of type any.

But why is it undefined? Shouldn't it be a array of any elements in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is because the original code used a declaration, while the update code has initialization.

### Declaration

Declaration tells the compiler the variable name and type. It does not give the variable a value (or rather, it gives it `undefined`). In other words, it *declares* what the variable is.

```js
public apps: any[]; // apps = undefined
```

### Initialization

To actually give the variable a value other than `undefined`, we have to *initialize* it.

```js
public apps = []; // apps = []
```

The compiler can then infer the type of the variable `apps`, which is, in this case, `Array<any>`

This alone isn't enough to explain why the compiler errors, however. Because you can keep a variable uninitialized as long as you give it a value later. However, you attempt to read the variable's length with `<div *ngIf="apps.length === 0">`, which results in an error (as `undefined` has no property `length`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to initialize the apps as `public apps: any[]; // apps = undefined`, then add judgement in `*ngIf`, like `<div *ngIf="apps !== undefined && apps.length === 0">`, also worked with no error. Think that proves your comment right.

Comment: I thought a little deeper and found a little confused here, maybe a silly question but I have to ask. Based on your comment, declaration has told the compiler variable **name** and **type**, but no **value**. What do you mean by **type** here? If it is data structure type, shouldn't the complier recognized that `apps` is an Array?

Comment: The `type` of a variable is what kind of values it can store. For example, a variable with type `int` can only store an integer, while a variable of type `Array<string>` can only store an array containing strings. `apps` has type `Array<any>` (or `any[]`, they mean the same thing), so it can store an array that contains any type of object.